# Dropping column from DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

When I created a column for my Rails model for attachments, I used:

```
def self.up
  change_table :updates do |t|
    t.attachment :image
  end
end

def self.down
  drop_attached_file :updates, :image
end
```

I tried to remove the column this way, but it says the relation doesn't exist:

```
remove_column :updates, :image
```

How can I properly drop this column from the Updates table???

**Update**
columns related to :image

```
t.string   "image_file_name"
t.string   "image_content_type"
t.integer  "image_file_size"
t.datetime "image_updated_at"
```

Comment: There's no column called `image`, is there? Look to see what columns you actually have, for example post the relevant section of your `db/schema.rb`.

Comment: No there's not just the related columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always remove those individually:

```
change_table :updates do |t|
  t.remove :image_file_name
  t.remove :image_content_type
  t.remove :image_file_size
  t.remove :image_updated_at
end
```

Comment: Ok thanks! That's what I thought about when I first took a look at my schema before I posted the problem, but didn't know about the attachment field since I created that. Thanks though @tadman

Answer (score 0):

You can also, use rake db:rollback to undo your last rake db:migrate